# Совместимость enum в ProtoBuf v2 и v3

Tags: google-protobuf

Пытаясь сделать свой генератор классов для ProtoBuf (нет "стандартного" для Delphi), наткнулся на интересное замечание: [Using proto2 Message Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#using-proto2-message-types)

> proto2 enums cannot be used in proto3 syntax.

Вопрос: почему?

Синтакс enum, насколько я вижу, ни чем не отличается в [версии 2](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#enum) и [версии 3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum)

В бинарном содержимом (хотя в упоминании о несовместимости нет ничего о `encoding`) - [нет разделения между версиями](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure), всё представлено в виде `varint`

Так в чем, собственно, выражается несовместимость?

Answer (score 1):

Единственное отличие `enum` в версии 2 и 3 - во фразе (v3)

> Enum definitions must start with enum value zero.

Источник: [ProtoBuf v3 specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#enum_definition). В остальном - синтаксис [один](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec#enum_definition) и [тот же](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec#enum_definition).

Весьма странно, что в руководстве используется категоричное заявление о несовместимости, хотя `enum` в версии 2 тоже можно начать с нулевого значения. Т.е. на мой взгляд, фраза должна была бы звучать как "если enum v2 не начинается с элемента со значением 0, его нельзя использовать в v3"

Comment: Да, в дополнение. Не знаю, реклама - не реклама, но я закончил свой генератор: https://github.com/kami-soft/ProtoBufGenerator  Использую его уже в нескольких проектах, полет нормальный.